# Ignore App Store updates in El Capitan?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, software-update

In previous versions of OS X, it was possible to right click on an update in the App Store and choose an option, "Ignore this update."

In OS X 10.11.6, nothing happens when I right click on an update in the App Store.  I do not get any menu.

According to [this article](http://osxdaily.com/2012/09/27/hide-software-updates-mac-app-store-os-x/), system updates can be ignored, but not third party apps.

Is there any way at all to ignore available updates in the App Store for selected third-party apps in OS X 10.11?

---

<sub>Apparently the current answer is "no"; however, I can hope that a workaround will someday become available, and this is the site where it should go.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Did you miss the Easter Egg?

For Software Updates, right-click the description text right under the title:

[image: hide software updates]

Got it from here: [Hide Software Updates from the App Store in Mac OS X](http://osxdaily.com/2012/09/27/hide-software-updates-mac-app-store-os-x/#comment-5450583) (last comment), though they say it doesn't work for Yosemite. I haven't checked if you can hide regular app updates the same way. I'll "update" this when one comes along.