# How to hide App Store updates in El Capitan? Right click won't work

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, software-update

The App store is nagging me to update OS X software (like iMovie, Photos) that I have no interest in. When I click or <kbd>Control</kbd>-click the white space of the suggested update I do not get a hide option (except for the banner for upgrading to Sierra, which I *have* hidden).

How do I hide an unwanted update?

[image: The app updates I wish to hide in App Store]

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of [my own unanswered question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/254527/151730).  I think the answer is, "You can't."

Comment: Thank you @Wildcard. Very similar question, although I am specifically interested in updates around OS X apps, not third party apps. Do you have a source for "You can't?"

Comment: See the article I linked to from my question; that's my only source.  (That, and an absence of results from googling and searching the apple forums.)

Answer (score 3):

I believe you simply need to change where you are clicking. See the screenshot below. Hide Update only showed up when right-clicking (or <kbd>Control</kbd>-clicking) in the green area, not the red areas.

[image]

Comment: that only works on _some_ updates, however

Comment: Thank you tubedogg! Unfortunately this does not seem to work. I have added a screen-grab of what shows on my App Store update tab... neither the top, nor the bottom of the bulleted descriptions work to [CTRL]-Click on. :(

Answer (score 1):

There’s `softwareupdate` command available in Terminal: [man page](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/softwareupdate.8.html)

Use `softwareupdate --list` command to get an identifier of the available update you want to hide. Then `softwareupdate --ignore`*`identifier`* to hide it. Note that the identifier should not include a version number.

Comment: hmmm, seems that even `softwareupdate` ignores KeyNote, Pages, Numbers and iMovie, all of which, like the original post, I never use

Answer (score -1):

Right click on the center part of the update then left click on shown HIDE...
Then move your cursor onto the upper wallpaper, in my case the SIERRA. Wait until the update vanishes. Repeat until there are no more updates left. Everything becomes blank.

Last update left is the El Capitan to Sierra (which I don't want)
Right click in the center of the SIERRA wallpaper and left click on shown HIDE...

Blank.